# Connecting to Oracle with PowerQuery - UI not working but SQL works fine

Tags: oracle, powerquery

I´m trying to connect to an Oracle database using PowerQuery. The connection works fine when I specify my own SQL (even something like select * from table); however when I select any table using the UI, PowerQuery just keeps trying to query the data, but the information is never displayed. I don´t get any error message or anything.

I´m interested in using the UI, because it´s easier and to take advantage of query folding.

I appreciate your thoughts on how to get this working properly. Thanks!

Comment: If you shared your code maybe someone would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off "Include relationship columns" (under advanced options, when creating the connection).

---

If that doesn't work, you can "Send a frown" to the product team.